# Change link of VideoView

Tags: android, video-streaming

I have a videoView, and I'm working with the link of the video.... but I want to be possible to change the link of the video that will appear in the VideoView by the application itself... Can you help me?

I want to do like this:  [Dialog](https://i.stack.imgur.com/SDdHz.png)

(+) When someone puts the link in the dialog box and clicks "Ok " will automatically change the URL there in the Activity class

My Activity:

```
package tk.protvapp.protv;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.net.Uri;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.Window;
import android.widget.MediaController;
import android.widget.VideoView;

public class FoxActivity extends Activity {
    VideoView myVideoView;
    View v;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_NO_TITLE);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_fox);

        myVideoView = (VideoView)this.findViewById(R.id.videofox1); MediaController mc = new MediaController(this); myVideoView.setMediaController(mc);
        final String urlStream = "change this text for the link...";
        myVideoView.start();
        myVideoView.findFocus();
        runOnUiThread(new Runnable() { @Override public void run() { myVideoView.setVideoURI(Uri.parse(urlStream)); } });
    }
    public void voltarhomefox(View v){
        Intent intent = new Intent(FoxActivity.this, HomeActivity.class);
        startActivity(intent);
    }
}
```

My layout:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:ads="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:background="#fff"
    tools:context="tk.protvapp.protv.FoxActivity">


    <Button
        android:id="@+id/button3"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:onClick="voltarhomefox"
        android:text="VOLTAR" />

        <VideoView
            android:id="@+id/videofox1"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content" />

</RelativeLayout>
```

Comment: Where is this `Edittext` located which is taking input of `URL`?

Comment: I don't think there's that yet...
  Just have where the URL would be...

Comment: Well then there is no question i guess . First build a `Dialog`(or fragment as per your need) . Look for tutorials .